# Custom Google+ URL without additional letters or numbers

Tags: google-plus

I want to configure a custom URL for my company's Google Plus account. After uploading a profile picture and validating my webpage, Google offers me the appropriate option but demands me to "add a few letters or numbers to make the URL unique to you." This implicates instead of `plus.google.com/c/Mycompany` I have to use something like `plus.google.com/c/Mycompany23`. This happens even though `Mycompany` (which is a placeholder) is relatively unique (which is a reason I chose it in the first place) and the name is available at G+. My questions are:

1. Is there any way around this requirement and to get `plus.google.com/c/Mycompany` **without** additional letter or number?
2. If not, is there any best practice or recommendation, which letters or numbers to choose? (".com" for instance is not allowed)